# Finding a pattern limited to a certain set of words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

Suppose I want to write a pattern that would capture sentences of this kind:

```
<person> was one of the few <profession> in <city> whom everybody admired.
```

The following delineate the variations needed:

```
<person> is a member of {Michael, Jack, Joe, Maria, Susan}.
<profession> is any of {painters, actors}.
<city> is the regexp pattern `[$k|K]a\w+`.
```

So, the pattern should catch sentences of this kind:

```
Jack was one of the few painters in Kansan whom everybody admired. 
Michael was one of the few actors in Karlsruhe whom everybody admired.
```

How could I model this in Python? As far as I know, regex alone is not able to capture patterns like this. I could maybe write context-free grammars, but before going that route I thought I might ask this here to see if there is a simpler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> import re
>>> persons = ['Michael', 'Jack', 'Joe', 'Maria', 'Susan']
>>> professions = ['painters', 'actors']
>>> regex = re.compile(r'{person} was one of the few {profession} in {city} whom everybody admired\.'
                         .format(person='|'.join(persons),
                         profession='|'.join(professions),
                         city='[$k|K]a\w+'))

>>> a = ['Jack was one of the few painters in Kansan whom everybody admired.', 
         'Michael was one of the few actors in Karlsruhe whom everybody admired.',   
         'Jone was one of the few painters in Kansan whom everybody admired.', 
         'Susan was one of the few foo in Kansan whom everybody admired.', 
         'Joe was one of the few actors in Kansan whom everybody admired.']


>>> for i in a:
...     regex.search(i)
...     
... 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='Jack'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='Michael'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='Joe'>
```

Comment: How would this perform, when the list of names is indeed 1000 entries? Is there an upper limit to regexes sizes in Python?

Comment: This is very feasible for cases when I have to process large sets. I am not sure about the performance aspect though.

Comment: @WardC I don't know, but if the list of names is indeed 1000 entries, then I think use regex here is not a good idea...

Comment: @KevinGuan What alternative would you suggest in that situation?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want something like this:

```
/^(Michael|Susan|Maria|Jack|Joe).*?(painters|actors).*?([P|K]a\w+).*$/gm
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gR8pM7/3)

PS: i've intended `$k` as a variable and replaced it with an actual value (in my case `P`), if you mean something different comment my answer, i'll fix the regex as well.

**CAVEAT**

Every solution using regex does not work as expected unless you sort the entries in the pipe groups by length (from the longest to the smallest).
In python use something like this:

`persons.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(len(y), len(x)))`

Why? A matching group just like this `(Maria|Joe|Jack|Mariano)` will never match the string `Mariano` because it will match `Maria` first and then stop to search just like any OR group in any common programming languages.

Comment: Suppose the list of people contained a thousand names on it. Would we list a thousand names in the pattern with pipes between them?

Comment: Yes you can, i've done this with nearly 8100 entry in Java. Remember to order the entries in the pipe group from the longest to the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

This [regex](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cw%2B)%20was%20one%20of%20the%20few%20(painters%7Cactors)%20in%20(%5B%24k%7CK%5Da%5Cw%2B)%20whom%20everybody%20admired.%20&test_string=Jack%20was%20one%20of%20the%20few%20painters%20in%20Kansan%20whom%20everybody%20admired.%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) catches your examples.

`(\w+) was one of the few (painters|actors) in ([$k|K]a\w+) whom everybody admired.`

**EDIT** Added example of how to check the groups

Say you want to check if the name is in a list with 1000 names, a regex will not suffice. You could capture the result of this regex, and add an additional check.

```
import re

input_strs = ['Jack was one of the few painters in Kansan whom everybody admired.',
              'Michael was one of the few actors in Karlsruhe whom everybody admired.']

allowed_names = ['Michael', 'John']

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+) was one of the few (painters|actors) in ([$k|K]a\w+) whom everybody admired.')

for input in input_strs:
    m = pattern.match(input)
    if m:
        # check if name is in the list
        name = m.group(1)
        print('name: ' + name)
        if name in allowed_names:
            print('ok')
        else:
            print('fail')
```

Comment: `\w+` accepts pretty much anybody who is not a member of the list of persons. And suppose that list contained a thousand names on it. Would we list a thousand names in the pattern with pipes between them?